# Implementing 2-legged OAuth to get user specific data for use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am diving into OAuth 2.0 to protect my RESTful services.  I own the consumer and the provider sides, and therefore do not need the end-user to allow access to the data on the provider.  I've experimented with client credentials flow, but this appears to only allow me to get a token for my whole client, but not for an individual user.  If I used the token for my client in Javascript, then it would be given to all users and wouldn't be very secure because users could potentially get data for all other users.

Is there a way that I can use 2-legged (aka client credentials) to get a user-specific token that can be used in Ajax/Javascript (similar to what the implicit flow provides, but without user approval)?

Thanks.

Comment: At least comment on your answers, please! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the ability to auto-approve clients, so the user does not have to authorize when certain clients access their data.  This works in my scenario because I am using the same single sign-on mechanism for both websites, and the login to the provider is transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the standard says nothing about user credentials for the "client credentials grant" scenario. However, if the protected resources belong to users, each token should be related to a specific user. Based on your question, I think this is the case.

If you're implementing the OAuth server, too, then you can easily do this. Just add a "user_id" parameter to the authorization request in the "client credentials grant" scenario. Processing the request on the server side, you can tie the token to the specified user. You may consider this as your own slight extension to the protocol.

You may also want to be completely standard-comformant and do nothing that's not written in stone, or you may not have access to the OAuth server implementation. In this case, you may try to use user-agnostic tokens (or "whole client" tokens as you called them in your question). However, accessing the protected resource, you must explicitly specify the user (e.g. as part of the resource path or in a query parameeter using HTTP) since it cannot be deduced from the token itself.

Comment: This might work, but I'd have to somewhat rewrite the intended usage of the client credentials use case. I am thinking that auto-approving certain clients would work better in my scenario since both the client and provider use the same authentication server (hence the user would not have to re-login when accessing the provider).